# Setting a minimum date and using that minimum date in a condition Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with emails converstaions with up to 5 different organizations. I want to be able to find the minimum date that a person reaceived an email then use that minimum date to only return all emails after that minimum date. Example

```
ID Date  To   BodyofEmail
A 1/1/14 Tom  hi hello
A 1/2/14 ABC  Afternoon
A 1/6/14 Tom  hi hello
B 1/2/14 ABC  Afternoon
B 1/3/14 Tom  hi hello
C 1/2/14 Tom  Afternoon
C 1/4/14 ABC  hi hello
C 1/8/14 Tom  Afternoon
```

What I want is, return all emails that were sent after it was first sent to ABC:

```
ID Date  To   BodyofEmail
A 1/2/14 ABC  Afternoon
A 1/6/14 Tom  hi hello
B 1/2/14 ABC  Afternoon
B 1/3/14 Tom  hi hello
C 1/4/14 ABC  hi hello
C 1/8/14 Tom  Afternoon
```

How can I set a minimum date in a query then use it in the where/condition clause of Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select the minimum date per person and then use it to select all columns from the table after that date.

```
with mindate as 
(select id, min(date) as mndt from tablename group by id)
select t.* 
from tablename t join mindate m 
on t.id = m.id and t.date > m.mndt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select c.*
from conversations c
where c.date >= (select min(c2.date) from conversations c2 where c2.to = 'ABC')
```